# passing timespan to facebook open graph

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I specify the time for my action to be presented in present or past?
I've tried -

```
$facebook -> api('/me/myapp:read', 'POST', array('expires_in' => '180', 'start_time' => date('c'), 'access_token' => $this -> session -> userdata('ftoken'), 'object' => base_url() . $data['link']));
```

but that doesn't work - so what am I not getting?

**Explanation**
`:read` is actually just the action in my facebook app. The post is happening and the "read" action is getting logged, the problem is that it is always presented in "past" as in

> Jakob read dadada on http://mysite.com

and not in present

> Jakob *is reading* dadad on http://mysite.com

My question is how I can have facebook present the status as *is reading* for 3 minutes after the action has been submitted (hence the `'expires_in' => '180'` which is 180 seconds equal to three minutes)

Comment: or maybe someone can confirm that this IS the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your start time is now, the easiest way is to specify "expires_in" as a POST variable. This is an optional parameter and will denote the duration (in seconds) for which your action should remain in the present tense.

From the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/):

> ### expires_in (integer)
>
> The number of seconds before this action is considered “old”. From the
>   time the action until expires_in seconds have elapsed, the action is
>   considered “present tense”, and afterwards, it is considered “past
>   tense”.
>
> expires_in is a shortcut for specifying end_time when it’s
>   more convenient to provide a delta in seconds between when an action
>   started and when it ends. For example, when a user starts watching a
>   movie, when you post a watch action, expires_in should be the length
>   of the movie in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Jakob, what are you trying to do?

> $facebook -> api('/me/myapp:read', 'POST', array('expires_in' => '180', 'start_time' => date('c'), 'access_token' => $this -> session -> userdata('ftoken'), 'object' => base_url() . $data['link']));

When you update something on Facebook, you issue POST command (2nd parm), what you are updating (1st parm; your wall, event, etc) and whatever data in the 3rd.

If you are trying to read something issue GET command. Not sure if you're trying to get all wall posts in your app or not. But if yes, try this:

```
$facebook->api('/YOURAPPID/feed?access_token'.$this -> session -> userdata('ftoken'),'GET');
```

**UPDATE**

Misunderstood the original question. Your call seems correct. If you're posting an action to your app and you configured Past/Present tenses (and plural versions) correctly in your Action Config page, it should display "reading" for 3 minutes and "read" after.

Comment: read is actually just the action in my facebook app. The post is happening and the "read" action is getting logged, the problem is that it is always presented in "past" as in "Jakob read dadada on http://mysite.com" and not in present "Jakob is reading dadad on http://mysite.com" My question is how I can have facebook present the status as "is reading" for 5 minutes after the action has been submitted

Comment: Sorry Jakob. Misunderstood your question. Your call seems correct. Action should expire in 180 seconds from date('c'). And you definitely specified correct tenses for past/present in action configuration screen?

Comment: thank you for confirming. Yes I have specified this correctly in the open graph action settings. Is this working for you?

Comment: Jakob, I never actually had the need to do actions so no. I have used FB api extensively for other things: wall posting, events, etc but have read the action api docs.  Maybe it's a date issue. The only things I can recommend are 1) try passing timestamp. I know the spec calls for date/time+timezone. I had an issue with Event object before (FB said must be ISO-8601 but in fact was taking timestamp only) 2) Try to set the date to yesterday and expires_in to something like 3 days. See if that gets you 'is reading'